# radiobutton hovering bug that cannot be solved by preventing it from garbage collection tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

I was going through some code and came across this one, where while hovering the mouse over the radiobuttons, the `Checkbutton` gets selected, I have tried keeping a reference to variable(shouldn't be needed as is already global), but it fails.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text_colors = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']
rads = []
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(2):
        col = text_colors.pop()
        val = IntVar()
        root.garbage_saver = val
        rads.append(Radiobutton(root,text=col,fg='red',variable=val))
        rads[-1].grid(row=i,column=j)

root.mainloop()
```

This bug is reproducible on my Windows 10, Python 3.9

Comment: You know that you keep over writing the variable `root.garbage_saver` so there is only 1 `IntVar` alive at all times.

Comment: @TheLizzard But I am using it ,`variable=val`, here, right after writing it right

Comment: Yes but I don't think that the Radiobutton keeps a reference of the object. It keeps the name of the object which would look something like this: "PY_VAR6" (note it is a string not a tkinter variable)

Comment: Also I recommend that you tell your `IntVar`s what their parent is. Use `val = IntVar(root)` instead of `val = IntVar()`. It will save you a lot of headaches if you use multiple `Tk()` windows

Comment: @TheLizzard Sure, I am aware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code without the bug:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text_colors = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
rads = []

val = IntVar(root)
val.set(-1)

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(2):
        col = text_colors.pop()
        rbutton = Radiobutton(root, text=col, fg="red", variable=val, value=i*2+j)
        rbutton.grid(row=i, column=j)
        rads.append(rbutton)

root.mainloop()
```

Basically you keep over writing the variables `root.garbage_saver` and `var` with the last `IntVar` object so it destroys the previous one. The behaviour is caused by tkinter unsetting the variable when it gets garbage collected.

`tkinter.__init__.py`:

```py
class Variable:
    """Class to define value holders for e.g. buttons.

    Subclasses StringVar, IntVar, DoubleVar, BooleanVar are specializations
    that constrain the type of the value returned from get()."""
    _default = ""
    _tk = None
    _tclCommands = None
    def __del__(self):
        """Unset the variable in Tcl."""
        if self._tk is None:
            return
        if self._tk.getboolean(self._tk.call("info", "exists", self._name)):
            self._tk.globalunsetvar(self._name)
        if self._tclCommands is not None:
            for name in self._tclCommands:
                #print '- Tkinter: deleted command', name
                self._tk.deletecommand(name)
            self._tclCommands = None
```

Note `tkinter` calls `self._tk.globalunsetvar(self._name)` which tells tcl/tk to unset the variable.

[Tcl/Tk docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_radiobutton.htm):
`"The widget sets the alternate state whenever the linked -variable is unset."`

Comment: Should've thought about this approach way back :p Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I still don't fully get why it confuses tkinter so much. The only event that should change the state of the button should be a `"<Button-1>"` event.

Comment: Hmmm well this is a bug.

Comment: @CoolCloud it isn't a bug it is a feature. I updated my answer with the explanation.

Comment: Make more sense now.

Comment: Note that in your example all the checkbutton gets ticked, I just want one to get ticked.

Comment: @CoolCloud 1 from each row/column or only 1 out of all of the buttons?

Comment: Need to just select 1 out of all.

Comment: @CoolCloud try it now